# MySQL Index on TEXT Column not Effective

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, entity-attribute-value

I've got a fairly straightforward table for storing key:value pairs, set up like:

```
CREATE TABLE `assetProperties` (
  `propertyKey` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `propertyValue` text NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `assetInstance_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK67F768435C68E1C0` (`id`),
  KEY `FK67F76843FBDFC83F` (`assetInstance_id`),
  KEY `keyIndex` (`propertyKey`),
  KEY `valIndex` (`propertyValue`(255)),
  CONSTRAINT `FK67F76843FBDFC83F` FOREIGN KEY (`assetInstance_id`) REFERENCES `assets` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

...and there are a reasonable number of entries in this table:

```
mysql> select count(*) from assetProperties;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 19931305 |
+----------+
```

...and what I want to do is find entries that exactly match a given key:value pair.  For example, using a query like:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM assetProperties WHERE propertyKey = "Wood Species" 
    AND propertyValue = "Jarrah";
```

Without any indexes on `propertyKey` and `propertyValue`, that query runs quite slowly, like on the order of 10+ seconds.  Which is to be expected.  The problem is, even after adding indexes on both fields, the query time is not improved.

The strange thing is, the index on `propertyKey` appears to be working correctly:

```
-- Before adding index
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM assetProperties WHERE propertyKey = "Wood Species";
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   339395 |
+----------+
1 row in set (9.37 sec)  <-- bad

-- After adding index
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM assetProperties WHERE propertyKey = "Wood Species";
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   339395 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.16 sec)  <-- reasonable
```

...while the index on `propertyValue` appears to have made little difference:

```
-- Before adding index
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM assetProperties WHERE propertyValue = "Jarrah";
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   219099 |
+----------+
1 row in set (12.51 sec)  <-- bad

-- After adding index
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM assetProperties WHERE propertyValue = "Jarrah";
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   219099 |
+----------+
1 row in set (9.75 sec)  <-- still garbage
```

The only difference between `propertyKey` and `propertyValue` is that the former is a `varchar(255)` column and the latter is `text`.  Is there something preventing MySQL from making efficient use of the index on the `text` column, or anything I can do to make the query faster?

**Edit**

Also tried adding a multi-column index across both fields.  Made no difference.

And further, if I add a new column (say `propertyValueShort`) of type `varchar(255)` and copy the values from `propertyValue` into the new column and set up the relevant indexes, it works as it should:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM assetProperties WHERE propertyKey = "Wood Species" AND propertyValueShort = "Jarrah";
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   219099 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.14 sec)  <-- acceptable
```

So that may be the immediate answer (the longest `propertyValue` currently in use is 88 characters, so I don't *really* need to be using `text` there).  However still doesn't explain *why* the index on the `text` column performs so poorly.

Comment: Can you post the output of EXPLAIN for those queries?

Answer (score 0):

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `keyIndex` (`propertyKey`),
```

-->

```
PRIMARY KEY(property_key, id),
INDEX(id),
```

Why?

- InnoDB "clusters" the PK with the data.  This means that all rows with the same `property_key` will now be "next to each other", thereby minimizing disk reads.
- Is `id` an `AUTO_INCREMENT`?  If so, `INDEX(id)` is sufficient; PK is not needed.  Else... Why have `id`?  Can you get rid of it?  Not really; you still need to make the PK unique somehow.

What is the `ROW_FORMAT` of the table?  How long is `property_value` typically?  Those impact whether 'big' fields such as TEXT are kept with the row, or stored separately.

(Bottom line:  key-value schemas suck.)